# Can tableau extract be loaded into R

Tags: r, tableau-api

I have a tableau extract.

I want to analyze the data in that tableau extract using R.

Does any one know how to load tableau extract into R?

Comment: In what form do you export the data from tableau? Or what exactly is a 'tableau extract'? I ask because there seem to be different options to export things from tableau according to http://kb.tableau.com/articles/knowledgebase/export-options

Comment: Tableau data extract is a .tde file which can be loaded into tableau and build reports. All the data in the database has been converted into .tde file and given to us to build dashboards. But i want to do some analytics using R before building dashboards.

Comment: For now i load .tde into tableau - build some tables - go to underlying data - export all data into excel and then load  that excel file into R

Comment: @Vadivel : You can configure tableau and R. Please refer to the following link. 
http://www.tableau.com/about/blog/2013/10/tableau-81-and-r-25327

Comment: Why don't you export the data to a CSV?

Answer (score 0):

A tableau data extract (.tde file) is a native tableau format. As far as I know you cannot read it directly without using tableau. So, you need to open it in tableau and then export the data if you want to take it out of tableau.

If you want all the data you can do something like this:
[image]

From here you can then paste into excel and save it as a .csv file which R can hit.

However, if you are happy to have the data in a .tde format you can always create R calculations in tableau. This is done by using rserver to communicated between R and tableau. See: https://www.tableau.com/sites/default/files/media/whitepaper-power-tableau-and-r.pdf